# Calling external ROS service from C++ code

Tags: c++, service, ros

How can I call a ROS-service that was neither written nor published by me from within C++ code?

I see the service listed when using `rosservice list`, which shows me

[image]

and I can call it easily by using `rosservice call /airsim_node/SimpleFlight1/takeoff` for instance.

Now, what I want, is to work with this service from within a C++ file (send request, receive response).

The [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) explains how to do this but requires you to have access to the service's source such as its compiled source code or even its *srv-file.

But I want to call an arbitrary service that is out of my scope. I, as a user, am able to do this via `rosservice call`, so I guess it should be simple to do the same via code?

Comment: You can find the `.srv` files [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/AirSim/tree/master/ros/src/airsim_ros_pkgs/srv).

Comment: Yes, I know, bit I want to be independent of that. I am looking for an approach where I don't need any source files and where I just need the same that I would need on the command line, which is: service name and data for the service request.

Comment: No, thats not possible since you need to know the service definitions for your implementation. You need at least the header files generated out of the ´.srv´ file. But you can generate them once and add them to your project manually.

Comment: This isn't something you can do with roscpp. It works with the command line partially because the CLI tools are written in Python.

Comment: Thank you for your replies so far. I am just wondering why this is so, because if I as a user call a service at the client-side, I do not need any .h files - I just need to know the type and format of the reequest-message.